# looking for guidance in my road to pure mathematics

Tags: education

During my teenage years I got into arts and slowly but surely I continue to pursue different art forms (poetry, music, painting, photography, etc) but it was just recently that I got interested in mathematics. I used to hate it in high school, mostly because it was thought as formulas to memorize and the results were only right or wrong with no room to understand why.

I was reading about mysticism & occultism which turned me on to numerology, and from there found myself mesmerized by pure mathematics. I'm not interested in applied mathematics, I just find it mundane and trivial while pure math is eternal, abstract and creative.

Right now I'm reviewing my high school topics so I can go into more complex ones. Being using a college algebra textbook I found in a public library and reading Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang.

I'm really a beginner still so if anyone can give me some tips or suggestions to grow into this divine pursuit of abstraction I'll appreciate it. Which topics would I need to have a good foundation to build my studies in pure, theoretical math?

Comment: Caricaturing applied maths as "mundane and trivial" as opposed to the "creative" pure maths is not a very good start. So my first suggestion would be to give up these preconceived ideas.

Comment: You might be interested in set theory. People with outlook on mathematics and penchant for abstraction similar to yours (used to be mine, too, it's not quite so definite any longer) tend to find it especially interesting.

Comment: What is numerology?